# Storing and retrieving session objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm storing an object in hash which is in session object like this :

```
    hash_key = ImportantData.new
    hash_key.test_id = params[:test_id]
    hash_key.user_id = params[:user_id]

    session[:important_data] ||= {}
    session[:important_data][hash_key] = nil
```

And then I print this map `session[:important_data][hash_key]` in my other controller and try to check whether the object is in there or not like this :

```
hash_key = ImportantData.new
hash_key.schedule_id = @test.id
hash_key.user_id = @user.id

in_hash = session[:important_data].has_key?(hash_key) unless session[:important_data].nil?
```

`in_hash` is always false to me, what am I doing wrong? and is there a better way to do this?

Comment: maybe it should be `session[:important_data]` instead of `session[:important]`?

Comment: Am I missing something? You're using two different classes of object as the keys in your two examples. If you want to retrieve the data in that session key, you need to use the same object (i.e. `object1.object_id == object2.object_id`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ruby, hash keys [work by equality](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html#label-Hash+Keys). You can store and retrieve a value in a hash as long as the key you're using is equal to the key that's stored.

For instance:

```
hsh = { 'hello' => 'world' }
p hsh['hello']        #=> "world"
'hello'.eql? 'hello'  #=> true
```

You can retrieve the value because the same value string is always `eql?` in Ruby.

This is not the case for most objects:

```
class Example; end

object1 = Example.new
object2 = Example.new
object1.eql? object2    #=> false
```

Therefore, the key that you use to store in the hash must be `eql?` to the one that you're using to retrieve. `eql?` is equivalent to [`==` and `equal?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Object.html#method-i-eql-3F).

You're creating two instances of `ImportantData`, which will not be equal to each other. It looks like you can accomplish what you want with a single hash key:

```
hash_value = ImportantData.new
hash_value.test_id = params[:test_id]
hash_value.user_id = params[:user_id]

session[:important_data] ||= hash_value
puts session[:important_data].class.name    #=> ImportantData
session[:important_data].test_id            #=> puts out value of test_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should assign it like this

```
session[:important_data][:hash_key] = hash_key
```

and access it

```
session[:important_data][:hash_key]
```